# Why is jquery returning undefined for checkbox "checked" attribute?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do something trivial and running into a problem. When retrieving the `checked` attribute of a checkbox, I'm getting `undefined` and I can't figure out why. What am I doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/YPYME/

```
console.log($("#invert").attr("checked"));
<input type="checkbox" id="invert"/> Invert Image
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because the element in question doesn't have a `checked` *attribute*. It has a `checked` *property* though:

```
console.log($("#invert").prop("checked")); // true or false
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/YPYME/1/).

Comment: THIS IS THE SECOND TIME I'VE MADE THIS MISTAKE. NEVER AGAIN. AS GOD IS MY WITNESS, I'LL NEVER CONFUSE `PROPERTY` AND `ATTRIBUTE` AGAIN.

Answer (score 2):

Use `prop()` instead `attr()` in 1.9.1

**DEMO** `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/YPYME/2/

Answer (score 1):

You're using jQuery 1.9 which uses the latest "prop" property instead of "attr" property which has been deprecated. Lower your jQuery version to < 1.6 or use ".prop".

Comment: The `.attr()` method has not been deprecated. It just returns `undefined` for attributes which do not exist on the element (in 1.6 and below it sometimes used property values instead of attribute values).